# pl sql error PLS-00103

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

I have a table(customer) and is has attributes of c_Id, fname, lname, age

the table is populated with the following values

```
 1|Ann|Smiths|23
 2|Chris|Gates|21
 3|Janes|Jobs|24
```

I am very new to pl/sql and I wrote a simple select statement

```
DECLEAR
     name varchar2(50);
BEGIN
     SELECT fname into name
     FROM customer
     WHERE fname= 'Ann';
END;
```

When I execute the script my from my textfile(doselect) on sqlplus using the following command

```
 EXECUTE doselect
```

however it gives me the following error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:  
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ":" when expecting one of the following: 
:= . ( @ % ;
```

Please help.

Comment: You've got a typo in your PLSQL script - it should be DECLARE instead of DECLEAR.

Comment: still having the same error despite changing it to DECLARE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the typo (DECLEAR instead of DECLARE), your script looks fine. To get output from SQL/Plus, I'd also add a `DBMS_OUTPUT` statement:

```
DECLARE
     name varchar2(50);
BEGIN
     SELECT fname into name
     FROM customer
     WHERE fname= 'Ann';
     -- print it
     dbms_output.put_line(name);
END;
```

However, to execute a file from SQL/Plus, don't use the `EXECUTE` command - rather use `@` :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> @doselect
 10  /
 Ann
```

SQL/Plus is not very friendly to new users - you might want to use another client to get started (e.g. [Oracle SQL/Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) - it's free and comes with a nice GUI).

Comment: @user3213758 You're welcome. One more tip: I'd ditch the "age" column and add a date_of_birth column instead - ages tend to change when people age.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
   name   VARCHAR2 (50);
BEGIN
   SELECT   FNAME
     INTO   name
     FROM   customer
    WHERE   FNAME = 'Ann';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ERROR ' || SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Your error is in DECLEAR -> DECLARE, and you must close your script with /.

You should always insert a block for exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Create a type `holding_TY` as an object

```
(
    d_id int not null,
    foreign key(d_id)references device(d_id),
    d_number number
)
```

Create type holding_nt as a table of `holding_TY`

```sql
CREATE TABLE bill (
    bi_id int primary key,
    c_id number not null,
    foreign key(c_id) references customer(c_id),
    bi_date date_TY,
    holding holding_nt,
    total_pri float
)
```

Nested table holding store as `holding_nt_table`